# MySQL add count field based on date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
id   num    date                Attempt
1    555    2015-01-03 01:00:00  1
1    555    2015-01-03 02:00:00  2
1    555    2015-01-03 03:00:00  3 
1    555    2015-01-01 04:03:03  4
1    555    2015-01-02 06:00:00  5
1    555    2015-01-06 17:55:24  6
1    555    2015-01-07 18:00:00  7
2    666    2015-01-07 01:00:00  1
2    666    2015-01-07 02:00:00  2
```

Hi, I have the above table layout but the "Attempts" field is blank.

I'm trying to update the attempts field based on the ID, Date.

I used this

```
SET @x = 0; 
UPDATE attempts 
SET attempt = (@x:=@x+1) ORDER BY id, date
```

The thing is I need to also add the group by clause so it picks up on the new id and restart the increment from 1 again as the numbering just continues onto the next id so my results currently look like:

```
id   num    date                 Attempt
1    555    2015-01-03 01:00:00  1
1    555    2015-01-03 02:00:00  2
1    555    2015-01-03 03:00:00  3 
1    555    2015-01-01 04:03:03  4
1    555    2015-01-02 06:00:00  5
1    555    2015-01-06 17:55:24  6
1    555    2015-01-07 18:00:00  7
2    666    2015-01-07 01:00:00  8
2    666    2015-01-07 02:00:00  9
```

So 8 & 9 should be 1 and 2 respectively due to the new ID.

Can anyone help with a bit of code to get my desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SET @x = 0; 
SET @num = -1;
UPDATE attempts 
    SET attempt = if(@num = num, @x := @x+1,
                     if(@num := num, @x := 1, @x := 1)
                    )
    ORDER BY id, date;
```

Do be clear whether you want to order by `id, date` or `num, date`.